# Report with 2 datasets and column groups

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

[image: Report design]

I need to create a report that is using 2 datasets. One (yellow) is bringing product data, the other (green) is bringing company and quantity data. They can both be linked using a unique ID field. 
One product may be used by up to 8 organisations and each organisation may have multiple departments.

Can someone explain how I can build a report to give the excel output as shown in the image.

I am familiar with lookup in SSRS, but not sure how to use this where groupings are required from the second dataset.

Comment: I would prefer subreport for this requirement. Multiple examples are available for ssrs subreport on web.

Comment: Can you join the dataset in database? That way, you easily achieve this using a matrix and column grouping with Organization

Comment: @PeterHe That would create multiple rows per product, so I assume I can just use row groupings to get rid of duplication?

Comment: Yes, you will need to use row grouping and column grouping